# How to keep query string in SEO MOD for phpBB

Tags: .htaccess, phpbb, phpbb3

We have urls like /section/page.html on our phpBB forum after setup SEO MOD.
But this mode remove all tracking parameters from query string.

How to keep query string in request?

Answer (score 0):

This is called URL rewriting and it is a good thing for **SEO**, however if you really want to remove it, you need to edit your *.htaccess* file in order to remove "*RewriteRule*" statement or add "*RewriteEngine Off*" at the begining of your *.htaccess* file.

Don't forget to do a backup of your .htaccess file before editing.

Comment: Thank you))I know what it is.

Comment: Promblem is that we need to keep query string after url rewriting

Comment: You should be able to have both. What is the content of your .htaccess file ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]

Comment: So, query string pass through this redirect, but removed in seo mod. I'm looking for an existing solution